# MQTT.js subscription receives multiples of the same message from the broker

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt, esp8266

I'm running on `CloudMQTT` and my JS code is this:

```
var mqtt_url = URL.parse('mqtt://m10.cloudmqtt.com:15272' || 'mqtt://localhost:1883');
var auth = (mqtt_url.auth || ':').split(':');
var url = "mqtt://" + mqtt_url.host;

var options = {
  port: mqtt_url.port,
  clientId: 'mqttjs_' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8),
  username: USERNAME,
  password: PASSWORD,
};

// Create a client connection
var client = mqtt.connect(url, options);

client.on('connect', function() { // When connected

  // subscribe to a topic
  client.subscribe('relay', function() {
    // when a message arrives, do something with it
    client.on('message', function(topic, message, packet) {
        // console.log(packet);
      console.log("Received '" + message + "' on '" + topic + "'");
    });
  });

  // subscribe to a topic
  client.subscribe('photoresistor', function() {
    // when a message arrives, do something with it
    client.on('message', function(topic, message, packet) {
      console.log("Received '" + message + "' on '" + topic + "'");
    });
  });

  // publish a message to a topic
  client.publish('relay', value, function() {
    console.log("Message of ", value, " is published");
    // client.end(); // Close the connection when published
  });

});
```

I have my `ESP8266` hooked up to a photoresistor, and it publishes the photoresistor value to the `photoresistor` topic once every 5 seconds.

Well, every 5 seconds I get four identical console logs on my Node server (MeteorJS).

```
I20170907-19:33:51.421(-4)? Received '156' on 'photoresistor'
I20170907-19:33:51.423(-4)? Received '156' on 'photoresistor'
I20170907-19:33:51.424(-4)? Received '156' on 'photoresistor'
I20170907-19:33:51.425(-4)? Received '156' on 'photoresistor'
I20170907-19:33:57.741(-4)? Received '39' on 'photoresistor'
I20170907-19:33:57.742(-4)? Received '39' on 'photoresistor'
I20170907-19:33:57.743(-4)? Received '39' on 'photoresistor'
I20170907-19:33:57.743(-4)? Received '39' on 'photoresistor'
I20170907-19:34:05.465(-4)? Received '37' on 'photoresistor'
I20170907-19:34:05.467(-4)? Received '37' on 'photoresistor'
I20170907-19:34:05.468(-4)? Received '37' on 'photoresistor'
I20170907-19:34:05.470(-4)? Received '37' on 'photoresistor'
I20170907-19:34:10.665(-4)? Received '161' on 'photoresistor'
I20170907-19:34:10.667(-4)? Received '161' on 'photoresistor'
I20170907-19:34:10.667(-4)? Received '161' on 'photoresistor'
I20170907-19:34:10.668(-4)? Received '161' on 'photoresistor'
```

Any idea what might be causing the `client.subscribe` function or CloudMQTT to output multiples of the same message?

Comment: Have you checked with a different client (e.g. mosquitto_sub) to see if there are multiple messages being published?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I am seeing the exact same issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in some scenarios, subscribing inside a connect event handler may lead to a duplicate subscription. An issue of this nature was addressed in [mqtt.js release 2.9.0](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/releases/tag/v2.9.0), as described [here](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/pull/635).
So, upgrading to the latest mqtt.js release (currently 2.13.1) might fix your problem.

However, note also that the [mqtt.js usage notes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#important-notes-for-existing-users) state that "from v2.0.0, subscriptions are restored upon reconnection if clean: true". See also [here](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js/issues/166). If so, it would seem that you don't actually need to subscribe at all from within your connect event handler, which should hopefully prevent duplicate subscriptions from occurring in the first place.

It should be possible for you to test the above hypothesis quite simply be restarting your CloudMQTT broker while your node.js client is connected. Does that cause you to start seeing duplicate messages? If so, I believe the remedy is indeed to simply move your subscribes outside of the connect event handler.